# Android Security Exception while accessing contacts

Tags: android, security, exception, contacts

This is totally weird and I've searched through the forums.

In my main class I have a button onClick will launch the contacts application as shown below. When I click the button, he contacts list is shown but as soon as I tap on a contact a security exception is thrown.

```
public void selectContacts(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case PICK_CONTACT:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber(id);
                    listOfContacts.add(phoneNumber);

                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("User didn't pick a contact");
                finish();
            }
            break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

I've checked the manifest and have tried all combinations of placing the uses-permission tag, within the application, activity etc. But nothing works. Here's my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.company.letsmeet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permision android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permision android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permision android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permision android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LetsmeetActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The security exception :

```
05-04 11:26:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/7 }} to activity {in.company.letsmeet/in.company.letsmeet.LetsmeetActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.SemcContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/contacts/7 from pid=3861, uid=10093 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm trying this on Android 2.1 Sony experia S10 mini.

Comment: Try out this [Commonsware's Example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick) in your sony experia first. And, let me know. Whether its working or not?

Comment: Thanks Akhil, the commnsware's example works. Strange. The manifest in that program does not have any permissions at all :). c'mon I can't be this stupid.

Comment: You have typo in uses-permision, need to beuses-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So guess what, I added the READ_CONTACTS permission in the Manifest GUI and it works. God I wasted an entire day on this. Hope others don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code.That may be helpful to you -

```
public class PickDemo extends Activity {
private static final int PICK_REQUEST=1337;
private static Uri CONTENT_URI=null;

static {
int sdk=new Integer(Build.VERSION.SDK).intValue();

if (sdk>=5) {
  try {
    Class<?> clazz=Class.forName("android.provider.ContactsContract$Contacts");

    CONTENT_URI=(Uri)clazz.getField("CONTENT_URI").get(clazz);
  }
  catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("PickDemo", "Exception when determining CONTENT_URI", t);
  }
}
else {
  CONTENT_URI=Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI;
}
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

if (CONTENT_URI==null) {
  Toast
    .makeText(this, "We are experiencing technical difficulties...",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
  finish();

  return;
}

setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pick);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);
  }
});
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==PICK_REQUEST) {
  if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                data.getData()));
  }
}
  }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      package="com.commonsware.android.contacts.pick"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="6" />
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="false" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/cw"
           android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".PickDemo">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

And, just refer [Commonsware's example.](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick) Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Commonsware's example works. My problem seems to be in the managedQuery call that I'm using. If I just have to view the selected contact as in the example, I commented the managedquery call and I don't see any error. Why would the managedquery call fail with a security exception.

Comment: Oh ok. When you're commenting your `managedQuery` that'll give you the result. Right?

Comment: Yep, if I remove the managedQuery call, I can tap on a conatact view the same as in that example.

Comment: Oh great. Then, post that as answer and accept it by yourself.